# Multivalue row count in Python

Tags: python, dataframe, count

Input:

```
col1 count
a,b   5
a,c   10
```

Output:

```
col1   count
a      15
b      5
c      10
```

I want to simply split col1 values and count respective total count in Python.
Question is mainly for learning simple tricks.
Is there any one line code to achieve this ?

Comment: I created a solution, If you don't want to go through the whole thing you can just skip to the end where I posted the whole code block.

Comment: I came back to check on the question and realized you said one line code. This is an oddly specific task that i'm not sure has a single line to complete it.

Comment: Hey, @pm980 Thanks for your help. But yeah I wanted to write code as small as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution i got is,

```
df = df.assign(col1=df['col1'].str.split(',')).explode('col1')
df = df.groupby(['col1']).sum().reset_index()
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes I have created a solution for you.

So to begin I created an excel file called input_file.xlsx formatted the same as your input so it looks exactly like: (REMEMBER TO KEEP THIS INPUT FILE IN THE SAME FILE AS YOUR PYTHON SCRIPT)

```
col1 count
a,b   5
a,c   10
```

Then I used the following code to go through it and append the first column to a list called col1 and the second appended the values to a list called count.

```
import pandas as pd
import xlsxwriter

df = pd.read_excel("input_file.xlsx")

col1 = []
count = []
for i in range(0, len(df["col1"])):
    col1.append(df["col1"][i])
    count.append(df["count"][i])
```

At this point the list col1 looks like this.

```
["a,b", "a,c"]
```

And the list count looks like this.

```
[5, 10]
```

So now I need to create these lists to become `['a','b','c']` and `[15,5,10]`

So I went ahead and did the count list first since it was easier. I used the following code to change it.

```
count = [sum(count)]+count
```

What this code does is it takes the sum of the list which is 15 and then adds it to the front. At this point the count list looks like this `[15, 5, 10]`

Next I need to change the col1 list to become what I need. So I used the following code and added the values to a new list called new_col.

```
new_col = []
new_col.append(col1[0][0])
for val in col1:
    new_col.append(val[2:])
```

At this point new_col looks like this `['a','b','c']`

Now you need a new file that will take these values.
So I am going to create a new file called "output_file.xlsx" and then write to a sheet called 'output' using the following code.

```
new_file = xlsxwriter.Workbook("output_file.xlsx")
new_file_sheet = new_file.add_worksheet("output")
new_file_sheet.write(0, 0, "col1")
new_file_sheet.write(0, 1, "count")
for num in range(0, len(new_col)):
    new_file_sheet.write(num+1, 0, new_col[num])
    new_file_sheet.write(num+1, 1, count[num])
new_file.close()
```

Now if you go open this excel file called "output_file.xlsx" you will see it looks like this

```
col1   count
a      15
b      5
c      10
```

So in conclusion in case you just want the whole code here it is. Hope this helps man, cheers.

```
import pandas as pd
import xlsxwriter

df = pd.read_excel("input_file.xlsx")

col1 = []
count = []
for i in range(0, len(df["col1"])):
    col1.append(df["col1"][i])
    count.append(df["count"][i])

#At this point col1 list should look like ["a,b", "a,c"] and count list should look like [5, 10]

count = [sum(count)]+count

#Now count is [15, 5, 10]

new_col = []
new_col.append(col1[0][0])
for val in col1:
    new_col.append(val[2:])

#Now new_col is ['a', 'b', 'c']
#Now its time to write them into a new file.

new_file = xlsxwriter.Workbook("output_file.xlsx")
new_file_sheet = new_file.add_worksheet("output")
new_file_sheet.write(0, 0, "col1")
new_file_sheet.write(0, 1, "count")
for num in range(0, len(new_col)):
    new_file_sheet.write(num+1, 0, new_col[num])
    new_file_sheet.write(num+1, 1, count[num])
new_file.close()
```